# Python3.5, Win32gui, Tkinter. I can't get Pixel from screen

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, win32gui

I'm trying to make Macro by using Python 3.5.

I made the program that searches the defined color from screen, then click it.

When I tested it just with console environment, it worked.
But when I added Tkinter GUI, it doesn't work.

The error message is

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\snowscale\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1550, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "D:/PyCharm/macro/main.py", line 39, in macro
    color = win32gui.GetPixel(dc, x, y)
pywintypes.error: (0, 'GetPixel', 'No error message is available')
```

How can I solve this? I'm just guessing something's wrong with DeviceContext, for instance Tkinter root affected it.

I'm not goot at Python and GUI. So I'll glad if you help me.

here's my code.

```
import win32api
import win32gui
import win32con
import time
from tkinter import *


Area_Set = { "center_square" : (684, 471, 978, 706), "vertical_rect" : (703, 420, 1022, 838), "horizontal_rect" : (546, 524, 1152, 713), "default" : (747, 485, 1029, 814) }

selectedColor = (13421568, 13172889, 14494037)
avoidColor = (14803425, 16777215, 6908265, 16645629, 14540253, 16711422, 15592941)

clickPos = (1335, 954)
confirmPos = (1128,431)
confirmColor = 16024898
interval_arr = [35, 25, 15, 6]
x_interval = 35


def macro():
    global Area_Set
    global selectedColor
    global avoidColor
    searchArea = Area_Set["center_square"]
    global clickPos
    global confirmPos
    global confirmColor
    global interval_arr
    global x_interval

    print("started")
    while True:
        dc = win32gui.GetDC(win32gui.GetActiveWindow())
        reset = False
        for interval in interval_arr:
            for y in range(searchArea[1], searchArea[3], 8):
                endflag = False
                for x in range(searchArea[0], searchArea[2], interval):
                    color = win32gui.GetPixel(dc, x, y)
                    if color in selectedColor:
                        win32api.SetCursorPos((x, y))
                        time.sleep(0.01)
                        win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0)
                        time.sleep(0.01)
                        win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0)
                        time.sleep(0.01)
                        win32api.SetCursorPos(clickPos)
                        time.sleep(0.01)
                        win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0)
                        time.sleep(0.01)
                        win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0)
                        if win32gui.GetPixel(DC, confirmPos[0], confirmPos[1]) == confirmColor:
                            reset = True
                            win32api.SetCursorPos(confirmPos)
                            time.sleep(0.01)
                            win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0)
                            time.sleep(0.01)
                            win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0)
                        endflag = True
                        break
                if endflag:
                    break
            if endflag:
                break
        if (reset):
            continue
        else:
            break
        win32gui.ReleaseDC(dc)


root = Tk()
btn = Button(root, text="start", command=macro)
btn.pack()
root.wm_attributes("-topmost", 1)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved. When I just changed

```
dc = win32gui.GetDC(win32gui.GetActiveWindow())
```

to

```
dc = win32gui.getDC(0)
```

it worked.